# Git: local branch which has no reference on server lost ref / path on local repo

Tags: git, github

I created this branch long back a month ago for testing some work, I had never pushed it remote branch, so it was in my local repository. After a month I checked out to master and updated the branch. Then I tried checking out to the local branch gets the below error msg.

```
$ git checkout branch_name 
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/heads/branch_name.
error: pathspec 'branch_name' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `git branch` to check if your branch is indeed referenced in that names.

You can also check its availability in `.git/refs/heads/<your_branch>`

If it is no longer there, check in [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) if you find your branch HEAD SHA1 back (see "[How to restore a deleted branch](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-restore-a-deleted-branch-765757540.html)")